# jQuery - sharing vars between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

This should be fairly simple; i'm pretty sure I've just not understood it.

FYI, the website is using jQuery to run ajax .load() on content.

On my main parent page, in the header I have my nav .load() jQuery code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a.nav').click(function() {
            page = $(this).attr('page');
            projID= $(this).attr('projID');

            if($("#mainRight").is(":visible")) { $('#mainRight').hide(200); }

            switch(page) {

            case 'projSettings': $("#mainRight").load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: projID}); break;
            case 'projMetrics': $("#mainRight").load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: '5000227' }); break;
            case 'projTags': $("#mainRight").load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: projID}); break;
            case 'projShare': $("#mainRight").load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: '5000227' }); break;

            }
            $('#mainRight').show(300);

        });
```

Now, basically I want the projID to be rememebred for use by other a.nav clicks that don't supply it.

An linked anchor calling this looks like `<a page="projSettings" projID="522" class="nav">Settings</a>` and I'd it to save that 522. So, other requests (that don't have the projID, as the data has been loaded into the DOM for other navs and they *don't know* the projID. I hope that makes sense.

So, I'd like to know how to have links like `<a page="projSettings" class="nav">settings</a>` when the projID has already been used in the previous call.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, ironically you're already saving `projID` globally (better said, within the `window object` by **not** using `var` in your declaration.

**So you already can access `projID` from everywhere in your code, once it's initialized.**

Anyways this is not a good pratice, opposite, it's a very bad pratice.

The best way I can think of is to create you own application object where you store all your data and access it from there.

```
var your_application = {
    var foo  = 'bar',
        base = 'ball';        
};

// your_application.foo = 'another bar';
```

You can push this principle pretty far with using **closures** and **functional programming**. An even better solution to store and keep data local and not global (window) could look like

```
var your_application = function(){
    var foo  = 'bar',
        base = 'ball';  

    return {
        getfoo: function(){
            return foo;
        },
        setfoo: function(newfoo){
            foo = newfoo;
        }
    };
});

var app = your_application();
app.setfoo('foobar!');
alert(app.getfoo());
```

That is the idea of **methodical** javascript programming. There a some good books out there, I would recommend to start of with `Javascript: the good parts` by Douglas Crockford.

Another solution for this should be the jQuery `.data()` method, which is capable of storing data in a global hash.

```
// store
$.data(document.body, 'projID', projID);

// access
var foo = $.data(document.body, 'projID');

// remove
$.removeData(document.body, 'projID');
```

Comment: hey jAndy ,,, can u please show us sample code??? its will be helpful for understand. Thanks a lots...

Comment: jAndy can u please give me some brief detail about base in  your_application.i mean whats the purpose of it here?
thanks

Comment: @Amit: You may never forget in javascript, there may be several other scripts that are loaded into a page. So storing data globally is just awful. Your variables can get overwritten which would break your app, etc. So a good plan is, to store your app data locally and even better, protect/hide them within a closure construct.

Comment: Hi Andy, how would you check if the data() store id exists?

Comment: @WiseDonkey: `if(typeof $.data(document.body, 'projID') !== 'undefined') {}`

Answer (score 0):

Just type the following line at start of your js script-

```
var projID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define variable outside a function and it will become global.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Make it global variable. 
Add var projID; at starting of script.
Agreed with Sadat.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have one function that is being applied as `.click()` handler for various `a.nav` elements, and you want the `projID` variable to only have to be set once and remembered for future calls of that same function.

This seems like the perfect use case for static variables. A static variable will retain its value between function calls, but is still scoped within that function. JavaScript doesn't have explicit static variables per se, but you can simulate them [by defining a variable as a member of that function](http://www.tipstrs.com/tip/1084/Static-variables-in-Javascript); the end result is the same. Here is the code from that link:

```
function countMyself() {
    // Check to see if the counter has been initialized
    if ( typeof countMyself.counter == 'undefined' ) {
        // It has not... perform the initilization
        countMyself.counter = 0;
    }

    // Do something stupid to indicate the value
    alert(++countMyself.counter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but the following modification should make it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var projID = null; // Better to have some default here

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a.nav').click(function() {
            var page = $(this).attr('page');
            projID= $(this).attr('projID') || projID;

            if($("#mainRight").is(":visible")) { $('#mainRight').hide(200); }

            switch(page) {

            case 'projSettings': $("#mainRight").load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: projID}); break;
            case 'projMetrics': $("#mainRight").load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: '5000227' }); break;
            case 'projTags': $("#mainRight").load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: projID}); break;
            case 'projShare': $("#mainRight").load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: '5000227' }); break;

            }
            $('#mainRight').show(300);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, and I made your codes more simple..

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var projID; // making it global
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a.nav').click(function() {
            page = $(this).attr('page');
            projID= $(this).attr('projID');

            if($("#mainRight").is(":visible")) { $('#mainRight').hide(200); }                

            switch(page) {

            case 'projMetrics': projID = '5000227'; break;
            case 'projShare': projID: '5000227'; break;

            }

            $('#mainRight').load("content.php?load=" + page, { projID: projID}, function(){
                   $(this).show();
            });

        });
     })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would prototypes not be better to do this with?

such as

```
function System()
{
    settings = {
       'Foo': 'Bar'
    }
}

//Then define a prototype
System.prototype.getSetting = function(key)
{
   return settings[key] || undefined;
}


System = new System();
alert(System.getSetting('Foo'));​
```

Comment: sure possible, but all variables are still `public` accessible.